# Constructing String from given Date object in Java

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I'm working with a calendar and a NoSQL database that stores data whenever a user clicks on a specific date in the calendar.

I'm currently storing data using nodes in format of `"YYYYMMDD"`

e.g. -

```
20190823:
       generatedKeyofUser: <user's data> 
20190824:
       generatedKeyofAnotherUser: <another's data>
```

I wish to be able to fetch not only the date the user has clicked on but also up to 4 days prior.

for example, if the user clicked on Jan 2nd 2019, I wish to query the database with the following dates `"20190102", "20190101, "20181231", "20181230"`

Currently I'm constructing a string in said format like so -

```
calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(event-> {
            Calendar clickedDate = event.getCalendar();
            Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, DateActivity.class);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            String year = Integer.toString(clickedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String month = new DecimalFormat("00").format(clickedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            String day = new DecimalFormat("00").format(clickedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            editor.putString("year", year);
            editor.putString("month", month);
            editor.putString("day",day );
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```

sending it to the other activity so it can fetch the user's data from the database.

**Edit:**
I edited my code as shown below -

```
calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(event-> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, DateActivity.class);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

            // Chosen date
            Calendar clickedDate = event.getCalendar();

            // Yesterday's chosen date
            Calendar clickedDateYesterday = (Calendar) clickedDate.clone();
            clickedDateYesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

            // Two days ago from chosen date
            Calendar clickedDateTwoDaysAgo = (Calendar) clickedDate.clone();
            clickedDateTwoDaysAgo.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);

            // Three days ago from chosen date
            Calendar clickedDateThreeDaysAgo = (Calendar) clickedDate.clone();
            clickedDateYesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            String formattedChosenDate = formatter.format(clickedDate.getTime());
            String formattedYesterdayChosenDate = formatter.format(clickedDateYesterday.getTime());
            String formattedTwoDaysAgoChosenDate = formatter.format(clickedDateTwoDaysAgo.getTime());
            String formattedThreeDaysAgoChosenDate = formatter.format(clickedDateThreeDaysAgo.getTime());
            Log.i("dates", "Chosen Date - " + formattedChosenDate + " ; Yesterday - " + formattedYesterdayChosenDate + " ; Two Days Ago - "+
                    formattedTwoDaysAgoChosenDate + " ; Three Days Ago - " + formattedThreeDaysAgoChosenDate);
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```

But the Log shows

```
Chosen Date - 20190808 ; Yesterday - 20190804 ; Two Days Ago - 20190806 ; Three Days Ago - 20190808
```

instead of

`Chosen Date - 20190808 ; Yesterday - 20190807 ; Two Days Ago - 20190806 ; Three Days Ago - 20190805`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You can use **calendar object**, it contains method `add()`, provide `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and pass **-1**. This code decrements it by 1.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar )   // Cast from interface to likely concrete class.
.toZonedDateTime()                     // Convert from legacy class to modern. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.minusDays( 1 )                        // Subtract a day to get same time-of-day yesterday. Returns a new `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(                               // Generate text.
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE   // Specify standard ISO 8601 "basic" format of YYYYMMDD.
)                                      // Returns a `String`.
```

> 20190807

…and…

```
GregorianCalendar.from (                    // Convert from modern `ZonedDateTime` class to legacy class.
    ( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar )    // Cast from interface to likely concrete class.
    .toZonedDateTime()                      // Convert from legacy class too modern. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .minusDays( 1 )                         // Subtract a day to get same time-of-day yesterday in the same zone. Returns a new `ZonedDateTime` object.
)                                           // Returns a `GregorianCalendar` object, which is also a `Calendar` object.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Apparently you are using an old calendaring widget that has yet to be updated to *java.time*. If so, convert by calling new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To convert from `Calendar` to [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), first cast to `GregorianCalendar`, the common concrete implementation.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) c ;
```

Now convert.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

You want only the date apparently, without the time-of-day and without the time zone. So extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate a textual representation of that date value using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Your desired format YYYYMMDD happens to be the “basic” variant of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format YYYY-MM-DD. Your desired formatting pattern is already defined as [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

## Date math

You also want yesterday and day before that.

```
LocalDate yesterday = ld.minusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalDate dayBeforeYesterday = ld.minusDays( 2 ) ;
```

## Start of day

If you want to convert back to a `Calendar` object, you need to think first about the time-of-day. A `Calendar` represents a moment, a date with time-of-day in the context of a time zone.

If you want to get the first moment of the day, let *java.time* determine that moment. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00.  Some days on some dates in some time zones may start at another time such as 01:00 because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

For the necessary zone, we can extract the zone used in our `ZonedDateTime` object converted from the `GregorianCalendar`.

```
ZoneId z = zdt.getZone() ;
ZonedDateTime startOfYesterday = yesterday.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Convert to `GregorianCalendar`.

```
 GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( startOfYesterday ) ;
```

Pass that `gc` (which is also a `Calendar` as well as a `GregorianCalendar`) to your calendaring widget.

If instead of first moment of the day, if you had wanted the same time-of-day as `zdt` we started with, do the date math on that object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtYesterdaySameTime = zdt.minusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtDayBeforeYesterdaySameTime = zdt.minusDays( 2 ) ;
```

Tip: Try to find a calendaring widget that uses `LocalDate` class, if the date is all you care about without time-of-day and without time zone.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to get the range, you can clone the current selection and remove the days you want (in your example, 4 days).

```java
Calendar clickedDate = event.getCalendar();
Calendar offsetDate = clickedDate.clone();
offset.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -4)
```

To format the value as you want, you can create a DateFormater to achieve that.

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String initialDate = formatter.format(offsetDate.getTime());
String finalDate = formatter.format(clickedDate.getTime());
```

If you wave to get all strings from the dates in the range, you can just run a "for", to iterate and generate the values between the two values, using the `.add` function as I showed in the first example.

Comment: It seems like it almost solved the problem but not quite. I have edited my question with your suggested answer.